# drawImage() smears image on JPanel but why?

Tags: java, graphics, awt, java-2d

I'm following [this](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/collision/) tutorial and when I animate my aliens from a PNG image using drawImage() my image smears on the JPanel and I'm not sure why that is, anyone know?

[more description of issue] As I move the image from the right side of the JPanel to the left there is a trace left. It like leaves a trail/footprint... I'm not sure what is causing it...

Here is a pic of what i'm talking about,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/337jx.jpg

Comment: Looks like you're not erasing the previous alien before drawing the new one.

Comment: How do I erase the previous alien? Thx for the help

Comment: Clear the entire BG each paint.

Comment: Thanks I got it to work. But it was because I wasn't calling the super.paint(g) method. I had the background color set in my constructor!

Comment: Your last comment would make a great answer.  Please put it as an answer & accept it.   Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. It was because I wasn't calling the super.paint(g) method. I had already set the background color my constructor!